# Identify my terminal session that started a particular process

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm using Gnome on Ubuntu.  I often have 8-20 terminal sessions open and in some of them I have su'd to a different user.  The specific problem that caused me to write this query happens when using *git status*, but this is more general issue.  *git status* will tell me I have an uncontrolled file .foo.java.swp.  This means that in one of my terminal sessions I have vi open on foo.java.

I need a script or tool that would tell me in which terminal session that vi is running.  I can do a "ps aux | grep vi" to pretty easily find the pid of the particular vi.  It would be nice if the tool highlighted the terminal on my task bar in some way.

Thanks.

-Sam

Comment: Did you consider using screen ?

Comment: Never heard of screen.  Just read the man page of byobu, the screen wrapper on Ubuntu.  It looks too heavyweight for my intermittent problem -- I'd have to give up two lines at the bottom of my monitor).

Comment: With screen by itself, you give up nothing.  Messages can be displayed over the last line or even in the windows title (hardstatus) - or you can give up some lines if you like.  It is only when you split the terminal (vertically or horizonally) that you are required to give up *a* line (for each pane).

Answer (score 1):

Each of your terminal windows will have a different pseudoterminal assigned, as accessible by the `tty` command. You can cross-reference this with the `TTY` column of your `ps u` output. For GUI integration, I usually found it sufficient to add the current pty identifier to my terminal's window title using [xtitle](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~kinzler/xtitle/), like

```
if [ "$PS1" ] ; then
  xtitle xterm $(tty)
fi
```

Jumping to a window by title is easy in my window manager, no idea about GNOME.